# take latest updates from main (master) to current working branch

Tags: git, tfs

I have started using git(TFS) recently. And for my provided task, I always create one branch work on it and than make pull request to merge that task to main (master) branch.

But my one of the works took long time and mean while master branch updated with many new functionalities (by other users). To verify my current work with latest master. I have to merge my current branch with master updates. For the same, I came across two ways.

1. Make a pull request from master to branch.
2. Rebase current branch from master.

Which one is better one? Why? Or any other ways too? Or I am doing something wrong for these 2 options?

Comment: Have you thought about stashing your changes from the master and un-stashing them in your branch? that might help

Comment: But from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing link, I come to know that stashing is used not to commit the unfurnished version and switch to master. Correct? But here I don't want to checkout to "master" I want to merge master updates to branch. Can you explain how stashing will be helpful here?

Comment: Okay, I might misunderstood the question. Sorry. What I would do is to script your current workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, option 2 is better. Which make the history and structure more clean. When you do the option 1(merge), it will create a new commit.

> **When to rebase vs. merge**
>
> Using **rebase** instead of merging branches results in an easier to
>   follow but **less exact history of commits.** Your team should agree
>   under what circumstances you should rebase a branch. You should still
>   always merge branches into the main branch through a pull request. A
>   suggested approach is to allow rebasing local changes that you have
>   made but haven't shared with others, but to merge once you are sharing
>   changes with others. This avoids trouble with rewriting history while
>   still letting you easily catch up with changes as you develop your
>   code locally.

You could use follow command to achieve what you want:

```
git checkout branch

git pull origin master --rebase
```

For more details, please take a look at this tutorial: [Apply changes with rebase](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/rebase). You can choose the way according to your needs.